# write a file to a certain folder, with relative path.When using wildfly

Tags: java, file, jboss, wildfly, filewriter

I write this file, that I would like to get into a certain folder in a project. The first problem is that I am using wildfly so if I just write.

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("swagger.json"))

the swagger.json is written in folder with path: C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin

I would like to write the file into the folder with the path: C:\Users\Mall\IdeaProjects\jim\jim-rest\src\main\webapp

The second problem, is that the file have to relatively written to the webapp folder. the reason is, that when run from another computer, the paths of wildfly and the project would be different from my own.

Any Ideas How I could manage this?

When using the code:

String.format("%s/%s", System.getProperty("user.dir"), this.getClass().getPackage().getName().replace(".", "/"));

I  get C:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\bin/com/soal/jim

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is not for production. Given that assumption it would probably be best to just have it prompt on where to save the file rather than trying to guess where to save it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following syntax ,remembering you start of in the /bin folder following snippet will create a file in /standalone/log

```
fileHandler = new FileHandler("./../standalone/log/BackgroundLogger.log");
```

of course this is risky for any unknown directory structure outside the server itself so handling exceptions is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared directory and write the file to that directory. It will make shared directory path constant for both the applications.

The path would be like **`/SomeMachineName/MY_FOLDER`**, and in both the applications, you can use the same path.